# Vectorise find closest date function

Tags: r, date

I would like to pass in a vector of dates, and have returned the closest date from a second vector of (partially matching) dates.

The following function does what I require for a single date, however i cannot figure out how to generalise this to the case where `searchDate` is a vector of dates.

```
closestDate <- function(searchDate, dateList, roundDown=FALSE){
  if (roundDown) {
    dist2date <- as.Date(dateList) - as.Date(searchDate)
    closest <- which(max(dist2date[dist2date<=0]) == dist2date)
  } else {
    dist2date <- as.Date(dateList) - as.Date(searchDate)
    closest <- which(min(dist2date[dist2date>=0]) == dist2date)
  }
  return(dateList[closest])
}

dateSeq <- seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2012-12-19"), by='day')
oddDates <- dateSeq[as.logical(1:length(dateSeq) %%2)]

closestDate('2012-12-14', oddDates)
[1] "2012-12-15"

miscDatesLong <- rep(c('2012-12-14', '2012-12-16', '2012-12-18'), 100 )
closestDate(miscDatesLong, oddDates)

closestDate(miscDatesLong, oddDates)
[1] "2012-12-15" "2012-12-17" "2012-12-19"
Warning message:
In unclass(time1) - unclass(time2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, with the example, just work on the subset of dates that are less than in one case or greater than in the other case, the particular target being examined at the time.

```
closestDt <- function(searchDate, dateList, roundDown=FALSE) 
     as.Date( sapply( searchDate , function (x) if( roundDown ){ 
                max( dateList[ dateList <= x ] ) } else {
                min( dateList[ dateList >= x])  } 
           ), "1970-01-01")
```

Comment: +1 thanks. I cannot use the Dates function you have suggested, as i need to be able to move between rounding forward and backward on the date. The `sapply` using a version of my function returns named numbers which are resistant to coercion back to date -- i have tried `melt(lapply(searchDate, FUN = function(x) matchDate(x, dateList)))[,1]` which seems to work, but would like to understand how i can make the `sapply` solution work.

Comment: The `as.Date` wrapped version returns Date-classed values. I do not understand the request to "move between rounding forward and backward on the date". Please post an example of what that means in practice.

Comment: @DWin just break ties in different directions ;)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico: I wasn't noticing the fact that 'ties' were being excluded. Modifying accordingly.

Comment: ties are not excluded: the two `closest` lines use _or equal to_ tests: for example `closest <- which(max(dist2date[dist2date<=0]) == dist2date)`

Comment: Are you sure this works? It doesn't seem to work if the dates in `searchDate` are smaller or bigger than those in `dateList`

Answer (score 5):

The `findInterval` function can do this quickly:

```
dateSeq <- seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2012-12-19"), by='day')
oddDates <- dateSeq[as.logical(1:length(dateSeq) %%2)]

oddDates[ findInterval(as.Date('2012-12-14'), oddDates)+1 ]

miscDatesLong <- rep(c('2012-12-14', '2012-12-16', '2012-12-18'), 100)

oddDates[ findInterval(as.Date(miscDatesLong), oddDates) + 1 ]
```

To round down instead of up remove the `+1`.  If you really want to find the closest date, not the one just before or after you can create a new list of dates that are the midpoints of the intervals (`as.Date(rowMeans(embed(as.numeric(oddDates),2)), '1960-01-01')`) and use `findInterval` on those.  See the arguments to `findInterval` for other options.

Comment: I thought I really understood `findInterval`, but you have just demonstrated that it has even greater powers than I imagined.

Comment: @DWin, for a while I have wanted to merge 2 data frames based on dates, but sometimes the dates did not match exactly so I wanted to merge based on closest or most recent date.  Just recently it clicked that using `findInterval` like above (though can simplify for the merge) would give me what I needed to do the merge.  Truly a great function.

Comment: +1, thanks that is a very neat function. I have been testing it, and it seems to return an exact match just fine, with rounding up and down controlled by tweaking the `+1` -- so i don't understand your advice to create mid intervals. What am i missing?

Comment: @ricardo, the original intervals were equally spaced so that will not matter much, but imagine if your date ranges were the 1st day of each month and you wanted Dec. 10 to round to Dec. 1 and Dec. 25 to round to Jan 1 (playing with the +1 will allow both to round to either Dec 1 or Jan 1, but not differently with the original intervals), then you could use the midpoints to create intervals (such as Nov 15, Dec 15, Jan 15, etc.), then Dec 10 and Dec 25 would be in different intervals and map to Dec 1 and Jan 1.  If your dates were very unevenly spaced then the midpoints would give the closest.

Answer (score 4):

`?Vectorize`

```
> closestDateV = Vectorize(closestDate,"searchDate")
> closestDateV(c('2012-12-15','2012-12-14'), oddDates)
2012-12-15 2012-12-14 
     15689      15689
```

The returned values have had their date-ness removed. So add it back:

```
> as.Date(closestDateV(c('2012-12-15','2012-12-14'), oddDates),origin="1970-01-01")
  2012-12-15   2012-12-14 
"2012-12-15" "2012-12-15"
```

You might want to wrap that all up in a new function.

Functional programming is fun!

Answer (score 2):

```
# initiate a tie-breaking function
tie.breaker <-
    function( x , y , la = look.after ){

        # if look.after is TRUE, eliminate all values below x
        # otherwise, eliminate all values above x
        if ( la ) y[ y < x ] <- NA else y[ y > x ] <- NA

        # then among the remaining values, figure out the date the shortest distance away
        z <- which.min( abs( x - y ) )[1]
        # use [1] to just take the first result, in case y contains duplicate dates

        # return z
        return( z )
    }

# initiate your main function
closestDate <- 
    function( searchDate , dateList , look.after = FALSE ){

        # apply a which.min( abs( ) ) command to each of the dates given, 
        # across every date in the larger list
        dist2date <- 
            sapply( 

                # on every element of searchDate..
                as.Date( searchDate ) ,

                # ..run the tie.breaker() function
                tie.breaker , 

                # and each time, pass in the dateList
                as.Date( dateList ) ,

                # and also the look.after TRUE/FALSE flag
                look.after
            )

        # return the matching dates in the same order as passed in
        dateList[ dist2date ]
    }

# try with two input dates
searchDate <- c( '2012-12-14' , '2012-11-18' )

# create a few dates to test against..
someDates <- c( '2012-11-12' ,  '2012-11-17' , '2012-12-15' , '2012-12-13' , '2012-12-15' , '2012-11-17' , '2012-11-20' )

# return the two dates closests to the inputted dates

# the first result gives 12/13, because look.after = FALSE
closestDate( searchDate , someDates )

# the first result gives 12/15, because look.after = TRUE
closestDate( searchDate , someDates , look.after = TRUE )

# reverse the order to prove it still works
someDates <- c( '2012-11-12' , '2012-11-17' , '2012-12-13' , '2012-12-15' , '2012-12-13' , '2012-12-15' , '2012-11-17' )

# the first result gives 12/13, because look.after = FALSE
closestDate( searchDate , someDates )

# the first result gives 12/15, because look.after = TRUE
closestDate( searchDate , someDates , look.after = TRUE )
```

Comment: +1 thanks. That's helpful. The way i have written the function is that it goes forward or backwards, even if it is not a tie. I think your only break the tie?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut`:

```
nearestDate <- function(dates,datesToMatch)
{
        dtm <- sort(datesToMatch)
        dtmMid <- dtm[-length(dtm)]+diff(dtm)/2
        as.Date(cut(dates,
        breaks=c(as.Date("1970-01-01"),
        dtmMid,as.Date("2100-01-01")),labels=dtm))
}

dates1 <- as.Date(c("2012-02-14","2012-06-23","2012-08-27","2012-12-01"))
dates2 <- as.Date(c("2012-04-01","2012-10-31","2012-12-25"))
nearestDate(dates1,dates2)
[1] "2012-04-01" "2012-04-01" "2012-10-31" "2012-12-25"
```

Note that I've had to pick some magic dates for the end points in the cut function since it does not accept +/-Inf. Amend as appropriate for you use.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
closestDate <- function(searchDate, dateList, roundDown=FALSE) {
  as.Date(sapply(as.Date(searchDate), function(x){
    dist <- abs(x - as.Date(dateList))
    closest <- dateList[which(min(dist) == dist)]
    return(ifelse(roundDown, min(closest), max(closest)))
  }), origin="1970-1-1")
}
```

sapply is your friend. You just have to make sure that a date is returned instead of an integer.